# Using std:sort to sort locally

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, global, local

I am making a Soduku solver, so I need to test for legality in the rows, columns and squares. I have functions to do each.

```
bool Board::isRowLegal(int row){
    sort(theBoard[row].begin(), theBoard[row].end());
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard[row].size() - 1; ++i){
        if(theBoard[row][i] != 0){
            if(theBoard[row][i] == theBoard[row][i + 1]){
                return false;           
            }   
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Board::isColumnLegal(int column){
    vector<int> currentColumn;
    int current = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.size(); ++i){
        currentColumn.push_back(theBoard[i][column]);
    }

    sort(currentColumn.begin(), currentColumn.end());
    for(int j = 0; j < currentColumn.size() - 1; ++j){
        if(currentColumn[j] != 0){
            if(currentColumn[j] == currentColumn[j + 1]){
                return false;           
            }   
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Board::isPanelLegal(int rowStart, int colStart){
    vector<int> currentPanel;
    for(int i = rowStart; i < rowStart + THREE; ++i){
        for(int j = colStart; j < colStart + THREE; ++j){
            currentPanel.push_back(theBoard[i][j]);
        }
    }
    sort(currentPanel.begin(), currentPanel.end());
    for(int k = 0; k < currentPanel.size() - 1; ++k){
        if(currentPanel[k] != ZERO){
            if(currentPanel[k] == currentPanel[k + 1]){
                return false;           
            }   
        }
    }   
    return true;
}
```

I sort the board so that I can test for duplicates. I run into the problem when my program hits the `isColumnLegal` function. It appears that the vector of the board has already been sorted corresponding to its rows, that means my column function cannot detect column legality because the rows do not correspond anymore. So my question is, is there a way to use the `std::sort` function, and sort locally, WITHOUT copying the `vector` into another `vector`? As you can imagine, this program is already inefficient and I hate to make it any more by copying vectors. I know it is only a 10 by 10 `vector` of `int` but still.

Comment: Can you show us how theBoard is made? Like its declaration?

Comment: theBoard is vector <vector<int > > , just a 2D vector that stores the values in a grid like formation, in the shape of a soduku puzzle. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was wondering. Would comment more, but Ben's answer below looks like a pretty good solution.

Comment: @TrevorHutto: `Board::isRowLegal` should be declared `const`; after all a check should not _change_ the board. `std::sort`, on the other hand, is a modifying operation. C++ typesafety could have helped you find the problem here. Also, see `std::adjacent_find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of 9 `bool` elements, initialized to false.  Loop through the vector, setting to true the indexes (minus one) of any number you find.  If, in this process, you run into an element that is already set to true, the row is invalid.

```
bool present[9] = {};
for (auto const i : theBoard[row])
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        if (present[i-1])
            return false;
        present[i-1] = true;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Cool, never thought about it that way. Nice tip. But do you know if it is possible to only sort locally to that function with the std::sort function?

Comment: @TrevorHutto: Not without copying the vector.

Comment: I'd use a `std::bitset<10>` instead. Actually, I'd use an `unsigned int` and write the bit operations myself, but that's because I can parse that kind of code just as fast. This code probably has to use memory; it's unlikely that a `bool[9]` can be stored in registers.